# Angular2 call modal form with parameters

Tags: modal-dialog, angular2-forms

I'am working on a angular2 project and I have issue when open  modal form with  parameters.

here is angular open modal snippet code:

```
openForm_modifyspace(content_modifyspace,event,name){

    this.modalService.open(content_modifyspace).result.then((result) => {
        this.closemodifyspace_result = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
        this.closemodifyspace_result = `Dismissed 
                    ${this.getDismissReason_modifyspace(reason)}`;
      });

    var idAttr = event.srcElement.attributes.name;
    var mydata = idAttr.nodeValue;

}
```

here is how I'am using mydata in template

```
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form >
              <p>title {{mydata}}</p>

            <div class="form-group">

            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
```

My question is to know how to open modal form with  mydata as parameter?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should set context where call open modal

```
this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, overlayConfigFactory({
    mydate: {}
}));
```

And after, get value in ModalComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mydate= this.dialog.context.mydate;
}
```